# Is it possible to manage MongoDB Users in NodeJs?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have been searching for this but all i can find is the CRUD of a collection named "users" with Moongose but i mean this users:

[image]

I hope to have explained my problem well. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible.

However, you can use the Atlas API to manage your users.
https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/api/database-users/

Answer (score 0):

In mongodb, you can. If you are asking especially **Atlas mongodb** I'm not sure.

https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/admin.html